# how to fix cycles in path using python?

Tags: python, dictionary, graph, expand

I have problem with computation cycles in my graph.
I want to

`graph = {('S','A'): ('2','2'), ('A','S'): ('2','2'), ('S','B'): ('3','5'),
         ('B','S'): ('3','5'), ('S','C'): ('3','6'), ('C','S'): ('3','6'),
         ('B','D'): ('4','5'), ('D','B'): ('4','5'), ('A','C'): ('2','2'),
         ('D','C'): ('3','4'), ('C','D'): ('3','4'), ('T','C'): ('5','8'),
         ('C','T'): ('8','5'), ('T','D'): ('4','7'), ('D','T'): ('4','7')}`

`print(graph)`

`{('S', 'A'): ('2', '2'), ('S', 'C'): ('3', '6'), ('T', 'C'): ('5', '8'), ('A', 'S'): ('2', '2'), ('D', 'T'): ('4', '7'), ('C', 'D'): ('3', '4'), ('D', 'B'): ('4', '5'), ('S', 'B'): ('3', '5'), ('C', 'T'): ('8', '5'), ('C', 'S'): ('3', '6'), ('B', 'S'): ('3', '5'), ('T', 'D'): ('4', '7'), ('B', 'D'): ('4', '5'), ('D', 'C'): ('3', '4'), ('A', 'C'): ('2', '2')}`

I want to expand graph but not there cycles. in example:
vs = `'S'`
vt = `'T'`

1. `('S', 'A'): ('2', '2'), ('S', 'B'): ('3', 5'), ('S', 'C'): ('3', '6')`
2. expand:

   - `('S', 'A', 'C') : ('S', 'A') + ('A', 'C') = ('2', '2') + ('2', '2') =

     ('4', '4')`
   - `('S', 'B', 'D') : ('S', 'B') + ('B', 'D') = ('3', '5') + ('4', '5') =
     ('7', '10')`
   - `('S', 'C', 'A') : not expand`
   - `('S', 'C', 'S') : not expand`
   - `('S', 'C', 'T') : ('S', 'C') + ('C', 'T') = ('3', '6') + ('5', '8') =
     ('8', '14')`
   - `('S', 'C', 'D') : ('S', 'C') + ('C', 'D') = ('3', '6') + ('3', '4') =
     ('6', '10')`
3. Output (expected):

   - `('S', 'A', 'C') : ('4', '4')`
   - `('S', 'B', 'D') : ('7', '10')`
   - `('S', 'C', 'A') : not expand`
   - `('S', 'C', 'S') : not expand`
   - `('S', 'C', 'T') : ('8', '14')`
   - `('S', 'C', 'D') : ('6', '10')`

May you help me about problem solving above? Thank you very much..

Answer (score 0):

I dont get your question but is this what you wish it to be?

```
graph = {('S','A'): ('2','2'), ('A','S'): ('2','2'), ('S','B'): ('3','5'),
         ('B','S'): ('3','5'), ('S','C'): ('3','6'), ('C','S'): ('3','6'),
         ('B','D'): ('4','5'), ('D','B'): ('4','5'), ('A','C'): ('2','2'),
         ('D','C'): ('3','4'), ('C','D'): ('3','4'), ('T','C'): ('5','8'),
         ('C','T'): ('8','5'), ('T','D'): ('4','7'), ('D','T'): ('4','7')}

sub = {}

for keys, values in graph.items():
    for keys2, values2 in graph.items():
        if keys[1] == keys2[0]:
            key = keys + keys2[1:]
            valueB= int(values[0]) + int(values2[0])
            valueE = int(values[1]) + int(values2[1])
            value = (str(valueB), str(valueE))
            sub[key] = value
print(sub)
```

Output:

```
{('S', 'A', 'S'): ('4', '4'), ('S', 'A', 'C'): ('4', '4'), ('A', 'S', 'A'): ('4', '4'), ('A', 'S', 'B'): ('5', '7'), ('A', 'S', 'C'): ('5', '8'), ('S', 'B', 'S'): ('6', '10'), ('S', 'B', 'D'): ('7', '10'), ('B', 'S', 'A'): ('5', '7'), ('B', 'S', 'B'): ('6', '10'), ('B', 'S', 'C'): ('6', '11'), ('S', 'C', 'S'): ('6', '12'), ('S', 'C', 'D'): ('6', '10'), ('S', 'C', 'T'): ('11', '11'), ('C', 'S', 'A'): ('5', '8'), ('C', 'S', 'B'): ('6', '11'), ('C', 'S', 'C'): ('6', '12'), ('B', 'D', 'B'): ('8', '10'), ('B', 'D', 'C'): ('7', '9'), ('B', 'D', 'T'): ('8', '12'), ('D', 'B', 'S'): ('7', '10'), ('D', 'B', 'D'): ('8', '10'), ('A', 'C', 'S'): ('5', '8'), ('A', 'C', 'D'): ('5', '6'), ('A', 'C', 'T'): ('10', '7'), ('D', 'C', 'S'): ('6', '10'), ('D', 'C', 'D'): ('6', '8'), ('D', 'C', 'T'): ('11', '9'), ('C', 'D', 'B'): ('7', '9'), ('C', 'D', 'C'): ('6', '8'), ('C', 'D', 'T'): ('7', '11'), ('T', 'C', 'S'): ('8', '14'), ('T', 'C', 'D'): ('8', '12'), ('T', 'C', 'T'): ('13', '13'), ('C', 'T', 'C'): ('13', '13'), ('C', 'T', 'D'): ('12', '12'), ('T', 'D', 'B'): ('8', '12'), ('T', 'D', 'C'): ('7', '11'), ('T', 'D', 'T'): ('8', '14'), ('D', 'T', 'C'): ('9', '15'), ('D', 'T', 'D'): ('8', '14')}
```

What my code do was just search for each key in the dictionary and then look for the ending character of first key and compare to second key beginning character. If sames, then I combine it. Then I will combine the values of these character and store it in a set.

I am learning as well but I wish to try to help so maybe some experts out there could help us.